# List view mass update action with dependant picklists

Tags: salesforce, salesforce-lightning

I got a list view where I need to mass update some records.

On the layout I have 3 picklists values : P1, P2, P3

P1 is controlling P2 and P2 is controlling P3.

Now when I update P1 and P2, it happens that sometimes P3 doesn't have a value for the selected P2 value so P3 is put at grey by the UI which is OK.

However if I previously had a value on P3, once I click on the update button, it's keeping the old value of P3 instead of putting it at blank.

I know I could handle it with triggers or put a value on P3 for every P2, but that's just weird that it doesn't come as a standard behaviour.

Am I missing something here ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try a onChange() event and handle it with JavaScript